# rsAccessDenied - SQL server 2008 reporting services

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs

I am running SQL server 2008 developer edition on windows vista home premium. I created a reporting services project that was built successfully in BIDS. When I try to deploy it it gives the following error:

```
Error rsAccessDenied : The permissions granted to user 'COMP\MYSELF' are insufficient for performing this operation.
```

The MYSELF account is the only account on the system. It has administrator rights. The reporting service is running with the LocalSystem service account.

If I log in with the MYSELF account into reportmanager, I cannot see the site settings tab. Without the site settings tab, how do I add or change the roles for MYSELF account.

In summary, please help me to open the reportmanager in the browser with the site settings link so that I can change the role of the user account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

I had to log into the system with the built in administrator account and then add the current user account to the administrator role in the Reporting services manager.

**Note that built in administrator account is different from an account which is part of administrators group.**

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on rboorgapally's answer...

1. On Windows 7, click on the Start
   button and then right-click on
   Computer
2. Click on Manage
3. Expand Local Users and Groups in the left panel
4. Click on the Users folder
5. Right-click on Administrator in the center panel
6. Click on Properties
7. Uncheck "Account is disabled" then click OK
8. With Administrator still selected, click on More Actions in the right panel
9. Select Set Password and provide a password

You can now log in to http://localhost/Reports as Administrator. Now set yourself as a System Administrator for Reporting Services by clicking on Site Settings in the upper-right hand section of the page and clicking on Role Assignment.

Finally, click on Home. Click on Folder Settings and set yourself as a Content Manager.

You may now disable Administrator and use your account to administer Reporting Services.